# FirePHP not returning ajax request queries, yet returns normal page load queries

Tags: javascript, ajax, zend-framework, zend-db, firephp

I am using firePHP(Zend profiler) on on FF 3.6.3(firephp addon installed) and it returns queries, when I do a normal page load.  Ajax requests, however, are not returning the proper queries.  I am using Prototype 1.6.0.2 for ajax requests.  Is there something I am missing?  Most of the write-ups seem to imply that this should work by default.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems and got through them after a firebug upgrade (check the getFirebug website)

Firefox has been going through several evolutions of how a sniffer should listen to the different network events going on. Attribution of ajax requests to the correct page is among the new difficulties.

For information, I have firebug 1.5.3

It might also be a firephp issue and you may check on their website if someone has already hit the issue.

I hope this will help you
Jerome WAGNER